# ES6 - Loop through array to post data to API

Tags: arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

I've been working on this script some time now and feel I'm getting close.

Input is in the format of `ONE,TWO,THREE...` I want to turn this into an array and then call my API to create a record by posting some data `Short description, description, site` looping through for each value in the array and returning a record for each pass. Input could be more of less than shown below

I see the following in my logs, but can't see where i'm going wrong.

```
{"error":{"detail":"Cannot decode: java.io.StringReader@1edc0c2","message":"Exception while reading request"},"status":"failure"}

Script failed with message: TypeError: apiRequest.end is not a function
```

**Example**

```
Call 1 - "ONE" - POST Data (Short description, description, site) -> Return result
Call 2 - "TWO" - POST Data (Short description, description, site) -> Return result
Call 3 - "ONE" - POST Data (Short description, description, site) -> Return result
........
```

**What I've got so far**

```
var tens = "ONE, TWO, THREE"
console.log(tens);
var letters = tens.split(',').map(string=>string.trim())
console.log(letters)
const apiCalls = callAPIs(letters) 

var data = {};

var short_description = input['summary'];
data.short_description = short_description;

var description = input['description'];
data.description = description;

var site = {};

switch (letters[0]) {

    case 'ONE':
        site = "O N.E";
        break;

    case 'TWO':
        site = "T W.O";
        break;

    case 'THREE':
        site = "T H.REE";
        break;

    case 'FOUR':
        site = "F O.UR";
        break;

}

var u_department = site;
data.u_department = u_department;

function callAPIs(letters) {
  responses = []
  letters.forEach(group => {
   var apiRequest = http.request({
    'endpoint': 'site',
    'path':'/api/v1/table/record', 
    'method': 'POST',
    "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    })
    apiRequest.write(group)
    apiRequest.end((data) => {
      responses.push(data)
    })
  })
  
  return responses
  console.log(responses)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> can't see where i'm going wrong.

Your error says exactly where you're going wrong:

> apiRequest.end is not a function

`apiRequest.end` is not a function yet you're trying to call it as if it were.